# Efficiently combine two lists resulting in a set of new lists

Tags: scala

I have two sets of lists:

```
A: {1 -> B -> 3, 4 -> B -> 5 }
B: { 7 -> 8 }
```

which I want to combine resulting in

```
A' : {1 -> 7 -> 8 -> 3, 4 -> 7 -> 8 -> 5 }
```

**Note**: There might be multiple references to `B` in the same list.

```
A: {B -> 1 -> B}
B: {2,3}
A' : {2 -> 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1 -> 3, 3 -> 1 ->2, 3 -> 1 -> 3}
```

My current approach is recursive and works on each of the individual lists of `A`:

```
object dummy {

    trait Step
    // I owe you referencing another set
    case class IOU(ref : String)
    // a simple step within the list
    case class Step(id : Long)

    def recursiveResolve(
                          id: String,
                          to: Set[Seq[Step]],
                          on: Seq[Step]): Set[Seq[Step]] = {
      on match {
          // here we are done and can return the empty set to resolve the recursion tree
        case Nil => Set()
          // we have still work left and now work on the first element remaining
        case mul :: tiple =>
          val step: Set[Seq[Step]] = mul match {
              // if we have an I owe you that references the replace in list
            case x: IOU if x.ref == id =>
              // return the replace in set of lists
              to
            case x => Set(Seq(x))
          }
          val next: Set[Seq[Step]] = recursiveResolve(id, to, tiple)
          // if the next step returned non empty we have to merge
          if (next.nonEmpty) {
            step.flatMap { elem: Seq[Step] =>
              next.map { nextElem: Seq[Step] =>
                elem ++ nextElem
              }
            } 
          } else {
            step
          }
      }
    }
  }

val A : Set[Seq[Step]] = Set( Seq( Step(1), IOU("B"), Step(3)), Seq( Step(4), IOU("B"), Step(5) ))
val B : Set[Seq[Step]] = Set( Seq(Step(7), Step(8) ) )
val result : Set[Seq[Step]] = A.flatMap(elem => recursiveResolve("B",B,elem))
```

This works but is obviously horribly inefficient as each step of the list involves consing and merging and flatMapping. Furthermore, the problem I am trying to solve involves larger lists, sometimes with multiple references per list to different or the same set.

**Is there a more efficient approach?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, yeah .. that becomes expensive (but still polynomial - I think, it's `O(A*N*B^2)`)

```
 def resolve(bs: Set[Seq[Step]])(s: Seq[Step]): Set[Seq[Step]] =  s match {
  case Seq(IOU(_), tail@_*) => bs.flatMap { b =>  resolve(bs)(tail).map(b ++: _) }
  case Seq(head, tail@_*) => resolve(bs)(tail).map(head +: _)
  case Seq() => Set(Seq()) 
 }
 
 A.flatMap(resolve(B))
```

Comment: B can be a set of lists. To keep the example simple I did not showcase it.

Comment: Right. Like I said, I have no idea what you intend to do with a set.

Comment: Then there would be even more lists
`A: {1 -> B -> 2} B{1,2}` should become `A: {1 -> 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2 -> 2}`. This problem has the potential for non polynomial growth, which is why I need to optimize it.

Comment: are you sure that the `resolve` uses a `flatMap` and not a `map`. I am getting a type error.

Comment: I think I found an issue with your solution
`A: { B -> 1 -> B } B: {2, 3}` should result in `A': {2 -> 1 -> 2, 2 -> 1 -> 3, 3 -> 1 -> 2, 3 -> 1 -> 3}` but only results in `A':{2 -> 1 -> 2, 3 -> 1 -> 3}` in your solution.

Comment: @Sim ok, how about now? [runme](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kV7iw4dETEemrmqBALM5yQ)

Comment: Thank you for your persistence! It does work. However, the special case of an empty set for `B` has to be handled separately. However, this is easy to detect and handle.